# Excel in Windows 10

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

In my target cell I want to subtract the numeric value in one cell from another cell's numeric value - but if one of those two cells contains a zero value, or if it contains the text "`ongoing`", I do not want any calculation to take place and my target cell to remain empty.

Any help with a formula would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: `=IF(OR(A1=0,A2=0,A1="ongoing",A2="ongoing"),"",A1-A2)`

Comment: When you say "contains", do you mean ="ongoing" or the cell has a bunch of stuff that includes "ongoing"?

Answer (score 0):

(sorry I'd rather have replied to Máté Juhász's comment, but my reputation only allows me to provide answers)

Máté Juhász's suggestion would work just fine, but *if* you wish the substraction to happen when either of your cells are empty, the formula should rather be `=IF(OR(AND(A1=0,A1<>""),AND(A2=0,A2<>""),A1="ongoing",A2="ongoing"),"",A1-A2)`:
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOz6u.png)

Comment: You and Máté Juhász agree that, if `A1` and `A2` are `0` and `0`, or even `3` and `0`, the result should be blank. But, under your variation, if `A1` and `A2` are both blank, the result is `0`, and if `A1` is `3` and `A2` is blank, then the result is `3`. It seems unlikely that your answer is what the OP wants.

Comment: Agreed. Hence my emphasis on the word _if_. IMO Máté Juhász should make his comment an answer since it answers the most likely scenario.